# How to split a string in equal chunks at certain character in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

So there is a string of values separated by \n.
for example:
"link1\nlink2\nlink3\nlink4\n"
I'm trying to send a message in telegram API but it has a length limit of 4050 characters. How can split the string into chunks of 4050 chars or less at \n characters so it doesn't mess up any links?
so I want the end result to be a list of strings containing 4050 characters or less, and the original list splitting points should be at "\n" character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/textwrap.html):

```
import textwrap
textwrap.wrap(s, width=4050)
```

example:

```
s = "link1\nlink2\nlink3\nlink4\n"*1000

# get chunks
chunks = textwrap.wrap(s, width=4050)

# get size
list(map(len, chunks))
#[4049, 4049, 4049, 4049, 4049, 3749]
```

Alternative to break on `\n` exactly:

```
def split(s, max_len=4050):
    out = []
    start = 0
    last_n = None
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '\n':
            last_n = i
        if i-start>max_len or i+1 == len(s):
            out.append(s[start:last_n+1])
            start = last_n+1
    return out
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question? OP wants the string to be split at every ```'\n'``` and any subsequent element in the list to be no longer than 4050 characters

Comment: @Nin17 OP wants to avoid breaking on URLs (not to split on **every** \n), which textwrap will do, no need to DV the answer ;)

Comment: 'the original list splitting points should be at "\n" character', 'chunks of 4050 chars or less'?

Comment: This just splits it into chunks of 4050 characters or less and removes the ```\n``` it doesn't split on ```\n```

Comment: Well, we'll see what OP thinks about it. I think your answer is incorrect (and note that I didn't DV it prematurely)

Comment: Hey, I need the string to split into smaller chunks of 4050 chars or less. It does that, but are you sure this code splits at \n?

Comment: @CryptoCircle it doesn't split at ```\n```

Comment: I mean I just want it to be 4050 chars and split at nearest \n

Comment: @CryptoCircle not necessarily, but it won't break words (unless extremely long and you can set an option to prevent it), IMO this is the most natural to break sentences.

Comment: @mozway it seem to work fine, only problem is sometimes it doesn't include some pieces of string if you put a smaller number for the width, for example 50. But since I will have a larger string I think it should be fine

Comment: @CryptoCircle I added a custom code that is doing what you defined, but this will fail if you have chunks without \n longer than the max!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` and list comprehension:

```
a = "link1\nlink2\nlink3\nlink4\n"
b = a.split('\n')
[i for i in b if len(i)<4050 and i]
```

Output:

```
['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']
```

Comment: This answer is likely incorrect, it will split the string on every "\n" and discard eventual substrings that are longer that 4050 characters. I doubt this is what is wanted

Comment: I need to be the result more like a single string with a length of no more that 4050 characters. More like ['link1\nlink2\link3....','....link80\nlink81\nlink82...'].

Comment: @CryptoCircle have you tested my answer?

Comment: @mozway yeah it seems to be what I am looking for but I need it to split the string at the latest \n char